# Why is animation starting on mouse down?

Tags: wpf, animation, styles

I have a stackpanel that consists of images:

```
<StackPanel Height="115" Name="stackPanel1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
    <!-- *******************Stackpanel resources****************************-->
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="100">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="0" />
                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="50">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="5" />
                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </Style.Resources>

            <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"></Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}" />
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard2}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <!-- *****************************************************************-->

    <!-- ***************** Stackpanel content: ************************** -->

    <Button Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}">
        <Image Name="imgAdd" Source="/WpfApp1;component/Add1.png"  />
    </Button>

    <Image Name="imgImport" Source="/WpfApp1;component/png-symbol.png" />
    <!-- ********************************************************** -->       

</StackPanel>
```

As you can see the resources of the stack panel contains 2 storyboards. One that starts when the mouse enters an image. And anotherone that plays when mouse leaves the image.

if you notice the children of the stackpanel are:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}">
    <Image Name="imgAdd" Source="/WpfApp1;component/Add1.png"  />
</Button>

<Image Name="imgImport" Source="/WpfApp1;component/png-symbol.png" />
```

note that one image is wrapped inside a button and the other  one is not.

**so my question is:** why storyboard2 plays when I hold the mouse down on the first child (the button) ? I only want storyboard2 to start when the mouse leaves the control not when I hold the mouse down. The second child (the Image) does not get that behavior and behaves the way I expect it to.

In case you need the style of the button that wraps the image here it is:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TransparentButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by preventing the event to tunnel by adding the event handler:

`PreviewMouseDown="Button_PreviewMouseDown"`

then setting `event.handled=true`

**in other words have:**

**XAML:**

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" 
        PreviewMouseDown="Button_PreviewMouseDown" 
        Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}">
    <Image Name="imgAdd" Source="/WpfApp1;component/Add1.png"  />
</Button>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
    private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true; // privent event from tunneling

        // then execute the command that was associated with the button
        ((Button)sender).Command.Execute(sender);

    }
```